# How to get value of a specific value of a list in C#

Tags: c#, list, winforms, loops

```
var ctsDB = mooe.Files66.ToList();
Dictionary<string, string> mappedfields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> ctsfieldsValue = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < ctsDB.Count; i++)
{
    foreach(var item in mappedfields) {
        // this line returns the item.key string not the value of it. 
        // item.key is the column name
        var rowValue = mooe.Files66.Select(k = >item.Key).ToList();

        // ctsfieldsValue.Add(item.Value, rowValue);
        ctsfieldsValue.ToList();
    }
}
```

I want to iterate through `ctsDB` List and get the row value of a specific 
column like this:

```
if ctsDB [i] =  fileID  Field612  Fiel613
```

and I have these column names in the value field of `ctsfieldsValue`.

I want to iterate on `ctsDB[i]` to get the value of column `Field612` only.
Can anyone provide a thought?

Comment: Believe it or not, a small amount of time spent formatting your code will positively increase the number of people who read and answer or comment on your question.

Comment: everytime I'm trying to add my code I got those quotes ,I dont know how to format it

Comment: I want to iterate through  ctsDB  list . ctsDB  is a list<file66> . it has a lot of columns .

Comment: How can I get the value of a specific column in LinQ ?

Comment: @RufusL  I modified it . can you please help ?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to share your problem. Your question has a low quality. What is your goal and your difficulty? What have you done so far? Please try to better explain your issue, your development environment and the data structures, as well as to share more code (no screenshot), images or sketches of the screen, and user stories or scenario diagrams. To help you improve your requests, please read the *[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)* and **Questions I avoid asking** at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ctsDB = mooe.Files66.ToList();
var mappedfields = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // I assume this is not empty in your real code.

var ctsfieldsValue = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

foreach (var row in ctsDB)
{
    var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var mapping in mappedfields)
    {   
        var v = row[mapping.Key]; //throws if not found
        d[mapping.Value] = v;
    }
    ctsfieldsValue.Add(d);
}
```